# Is there a name for this kind of design/illustration?

Tags: style-identification

Characteristics: long rounded rectangles used to compose the entire scene.

[image: Cosmic Beach by Samuel Tyler, his debut shot on Dribbble.]

Comment: Not every art form has a distinctive name. For this, "70s minimalistic art" brings up a lot of similar images.

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric design. Specifically, try searching "geometric design patterns", and then play along with the shapes (circles, squares etc.)

Answer (score -1):

It also looks like flat design

Comment: Hello haileyerickson, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!